# Flask Socket-IO and React socket.io-client, client doesn't receive messages from 'emit

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, multithreading, flask-socketio

I want to send message to client (React JS) from another thread (because there I start basic consuming messages from pika and it blocks Flask app).
That's my simple code at client side:

```
const socket = io.connect('ws://127.0.0.1:5000',{transports: ['websocket'], secure: true, port: '5000'});

useEffect(()=> {
    socket.emit("echo", "echo");
}, [])

socket.on('echoresponse', (data) => {
    console.log(data);
});


socket.on('update_page', (data) => {
    console.log(data);
});
```

When server receives echo, it answers back and everything work ok.
But when I try to emit from send_result_in_thread(), client receives nothing.
My server side (missing some rabbitmq pika code)

```
    clients = []
    app = Flask(__name__)
    socketIo = SocketIO(app, async_mode='eventlet', cors_allowed_origins="*")
    eventlet.monkey_patch()
    app.debug = True
    app.host = 'localhost'
    app.debug = True
    app.host = 'localhost'
    
 def send_result_in_thread(cli, message):
    for client in cli:
            socketIo.emit('update_page', message, room=client)
            print('sending message "{}" to client {}'.format(message.decode("utf-8"), client))
    
@socketIo.on("echo")
def echo( message):
     emit('echoresponse', "I'm alive")
    
@socketIo.on('connect')
  def handle_connect():
      print('Client connected')
      clients.append(request.sid)
    
    
@socketIo.on('disconnect')
def handle_disconnect():
     print('Client disconnected')
     clients.remove(request.sid)
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    consumer = consumer.Consumer()
    t = threading.Thread(target=consumer.run, name="run", args=(clients, ))
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()
    socketIo.run(app, host='0.0.0.0', port='5000',
                     debug=True)
```

Another thread:

```
class Consumer():
    def __init__(self):
        self.clients = []
        #and some more code for rabbitmq

    def got_result(self, ch, method, properties, body):
        print("CLIENTS from thread:" + str(self.clients))
        socketIo.start_background_task(send_result_in_thread, self.clients, body)

    def run(self, clients):
        self.clients = clients
        self.channel.basic_consume(self.queue_name, self.got_result)
        self.channel.start_consuming()
```

I found similar problem here and used as a reference https://stackoverrun.com/ru/q/12599436
But it doesn't help solving the problem. Client_id is passed to thread successfully, the send_result_in_thread is called but client doesn't receive message. I have no idea why.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Set a breakpoint to see if any connection is made and set your echo to run on the connected event callback.

Comment: Thanks, I solved it! the problem was different socketIo objects in threads @John

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I've found the problem. Every thread had his own socketIo variable, so message was not send to client. My solution:
In main:

```
t = threading.Thread(target=consumer.run, name="run", args=(clients, socketIo))
```

In run:

```
self.socketIo = socketIo
```

And in got_result:

```
performer.socketIo.start_background_task(performer.send_result_in_thread, self.clients, self.socketIo, body.decode("utf-8"))
```